# 2 MB of GIF images consuming 8 MB of memory

Tags: ios, memory-management, ios-extensions

I am creating a **Keyboard Extensions**, which shows animated GIF images, at a time it shows only max 2MB of images distributed in 20 GIFs all together.

Whenever the GIFs are loaded, the memory consumption increases by more than 8MB, which is causing **Memory Pressure**, and the keyboard is getting terminated as soon as it is loaded.

I am using `SDWebImage` to show the GIFs.

Can anyone suggest me, how should I use GIFs, or is it good idea to show animated GIFs in keyboard extensions? Why is the extension taking up so much memory?

Thank You.

Comment: GIFs are compressed. A 2MB GIF image generally contains more than 2MB of raw information.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Yes but how much? If it is upto 4MB still its OK..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SDWebImage has a lot of features so the object would be very heavy. Try to use FLAnimatedImage. It is made specifically for showing GIFs

Comment: Finger crossed! Let me know how it is doing :)

Comment: Yes it works much better with FLAnimatedImage than SDWebImage, the crash frequency reduced a lot. Thanks.

Comment: If you get memory warning you can nil out unnecessary images in didreceivememirywarning method!

Comment: Use [DFImageManager](https://github.com/kean/DFImageManager) if you want to automate FLAnimatedImage integration. It's a [better alternative](https://github.com/kean/DFImageManager/wiki/How-is-DFImageManager-better-than-SDWebImage) to SDWebImage. And it's very good at managing memory cache.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage) with [Nuke](https://github.com/kean/Nuke) which automatically integrates FLAnimatedImage for you. FLAnimatedImage is the best in class animated GIF engine for iOS at the moment.

The problem with SDWebImage is that they have their own implementation of animated GIFs. They iterate thought all the frames and create bitmaps upfront:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    CGImageRef image = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, i, NULL);
    duration += [self sd_frameDurationAtIndex:i source:source];
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:image scale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp]];
    CGImageRelease(image);
}
```

FLAnimatedImage on the other hand creates bitmaps on-demand and intelligently caches them.

Answer (score 0):

When the GIFs are loaded they will be decompressed so they will take a lot more space in memory. This is because iOS needs the images in raw bitmap format in order to edit or display them.

The GIF format has a very good compression ratio with the limitation of having only a 8bpp color space. So a 4x compression in your case is very likely.

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: Use smaller images. However 8MB of data does not seem that much even for a 4S.

Comment: Yes using smaller Gifs around 40-50 KB, may be some bigger GIF spikes up the memory usage, though there is a problem with SDWebImage, it consumes more memory than normal, am checking if it works, all fine. Thanks.